# Is it possible to switch lockedTaskMode for device enrolled with Android Management API programmatically?

Tags: mdm, android-management-api, emm

I develop an android kiosk application. I want my app to start automatically when device boots and run in "locked task" mode most of the time. But I also need to be able to switch off "locked task" mode programmatically from the app for maintenance/debugging.

Now I'm planing to enroll tablets with Android Management API (QRCode) to

1. autostart app when device boot and run it in "locked task" mode without "Pin dialog" notification
2. simplify initial device setup
3. simplify app auto-update

Does anyone have an idea how to configure device with Android Management API to be able to to switch on/off "locked task" mode programmatically?

I can't just white list apps because I'm not sure which apps I'll need.

I tried to set install type to "KIOSK" for my app. DPC locks task for my app in this case but I can't stop this mode. App just restarts when I call `stopLockTask()`.

And it looks like when I set install type just to `REQUIRED_FOR_SETUP` I can't start locked task mode because my app is not whitelisted for that.

I also tried to play with `kioskCustomLauncherEnabled` option. But if I set this to "true" it becomes impossible to setup my app as a launcher to auto start with device.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off of lock task mode by using a different install type in the policy (e.g. change install type from `KIOSK` to `FORCE_INSTALLED`).
You may also want to implement a maintenance window to ensure that device updates are done when the device is not in use.

You can check the official documentation for more information about dedicated devices: https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices?hl=en#kiosk-mode